# How to manage future updates for my APPs and site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, backup, installation, restore

My SharePoint 2013 environments are as follow:-

1. I have three environments; Development, staging, production.
2. Currently I have developed an intranet for our company, on the development env, then I restore it to my staging where I did the UAT and I applied the changes. Then finally I restore the site collection to production.

Currently the SharePoint server 2013 is on production and everything seems to be working fine. But I am afraid of the following scenarios in the future:-

1. Currently the SP 2013 on production is being updated with real data, so in the future if a new requirement or change request was initiated, how I can test and restore the site collection from development, to staging to production ?
2. And if some changes were requested on an existing Site collection (most probably will happen), how I will be able to apply the changes without having to recreate the Apps. Should I in this case be manually modifying the site collection on production and staging? For example if a new requirement was issued to add a new custom column to my current announcement list APP . Do I have to manually add the custom column on the three environments separately. Currently as this was my first SharePoint site I was able to create the announcement list on my development server and then restore it to my staging and production. But if changes are issued on existing site collection what will be the process ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have to manually add the custom column on the three environments separately. We too have similar environments and we too do the same process.

You make your changes as features and deploy them to each environments using Power Shell or stsadm commands. Since Features support upgrade and you can have versions as  well.

Comment: but doing everything using features will take a lot of time and effort. so you mean you have faced the same scenario becuase you are not using features ?

Comment: What I meant to say was, after production environment gone live, instead of restoring UAT environment to production again and again for each and every changes, create Visual studio solution(wsps) for further changes and enhancements.